# Реализация шаблона матрицы

Tags: c++, матрицы

Передо мной стоит задача: «Разработать параметризованный класс для представления матрицы произвольных размеров. Создать конструкторы и деструктор, перегрузить операции сложения, вычитания и умножения (согласно правилам работы с матрицами), обращение по индексу, ввода из потока и вывода в поток. Создать собственные классы исключений и генерировать соответствующие объекты-исключения, если невозможно выполнить ту или иную операцию.»

Я написал следующий код:

```
// matrix.h
#pragma once
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H
template <typename Type>
class Matrix {
    private:
        int rowCount;
        int columnCount;
        int size;
        Matrix *ptr;
    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(int, int);
        ~Matrix();
        void setMatrix();
        void getMatrix();
        Type* operator [](int);
        Matrix operator+(const Matrix &);
        Matrix operator-(const Matrix &);
        Matrix operator *(const Matrix &);
        Type *minPositive();
};
#endif


// matrix.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type>::Matrix() {
    printf("Введите кол-во строк матрицы: ");
    cin >> rowCount;
    printf("Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы: ");
    cin >> columnCount;
    Type **prt = new Type*[rowCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        ptr[i] = new Type[columnCount];
    }
}

template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type>::Matrix(int rowSize, int columnSize) {
    rowCount = rowSize;
    columnCount = columnSize;
    Type **arrayPointer = new Type*[rowCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        ptr[i] = new Type[columnCount];
    }
}

template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type>::~Matrix() {
    delete[] ptr;
}

template <typename Type>
void Matrix<Type>::setMatrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
            ptr[i][j] = rand() % 50;
        }
    }
}

template <typename Type>
void Matrix<Type>::getMatrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
            cout << setw(4) << ptr[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
}

template <typename Type>
Type*::operator [](int subscript) {
    size = rowCount + columnCount;
    if (subscript < 0 || subscript >= size) {
        cerr << "\n Ошибка индекса: " << subscript << endl;
        exit(1); 
    }
    return ptr[subscript]; 
}


template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type> Matrix<Type>::operator +(const Matrix<Type> &M) {
    return Matrix<Type>(*this).operator+=(M);
}

template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type> Matrix<Type>::operator -(const Matrix<Type> &M) {
    return Matrix<Type>(*this).operator-=(M);
}

template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type> Matrix<Type>::operator *(const Matrix<Type> &M) {
    return Matrix<Type>(*this).operator*=(M);
}

// main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include "matrix.h"
using namespace std;

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    try {
        Matrix<double> matrix;
        matrix.setMatrix();
        matrix.getMatrix();
    }
    catch (const exception&) {

    }
    _getch();
}
```

Visual studio выдает ошибку компиляции:

> ```
> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall
> Matrix<double>::Matrix<double>(void)" (??0?$Matrix@N@@QAE@XZ) в функции _main
> ```

Что не так или где ошибка в коде?

Comment: @Abyx, честно, не вижу связи

Comment: @Overthesanity: Связь самая прямая. Если короче: для шаблонного класса не морочьте себе голову и определяйте все функции прямо в .h, внутри класса.

Comment: @VladD, я понимаю, но лектор требует разбить на 2 файла

Comment: Скажите лектору, что он не знает C++. Постарайтесь сделать это вежливо.

Comment: @Abyx, окей, щас погуглю

Comment: @Overthesanity: Вот вам из официального FAQ: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl

Comment: @VladD, объясню так, глупо конечно, но все же, задание, как таковое, можно сделать без шаблонов, но лектор сказал, что без шаблонов 5 не поставит...

Comment: @Overthesanity: И без двух файлов тоже не поставит?

Comment: @Abyx: Хм, неужели [это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/12586/10105) канонический ответ?

Comment: @VladD, ну это "якобы" обязательные требования от самого лектора

Comment: @VladD, хорошо, то есть можно код из .cpp файла перенести в .h и попробовать?

Comment: @Overthesanity: Нет, внесите функции внутрь `class { ... };`, иначе будут ошибки multiple definition чего-то-там. Или кажется можно использовать `inline` (не уверен).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, щас попробую

Comment: @VladD, определил все функции в самом классе, уже нет ошибки линковщика, но есть ошибка C2440 =: невозможно преобразовать "int" в "double *", ссылается на ptr[i][j] = rand() % 50; prt у меня определен в параметрах класса как указатель на массив Matrix<Type> *ptr;

Comment: @Overthesanity: Если `ptr` — это `Matrix<Type>*`, то `ptr[i]` имеет тип `Matrix<Type>`, а `ptr[i][j]` — `double*`. Наверное, вы имели в виду `(*ptr)[i][j]`?

Comment: @VladD, заменил на (*ptr)[i][j], Ошибка C2109 для индекса требуется массив или указатель

Comment: @Overthesanity: `Type*::operator [](int subscript)` неправильно, надо `Type* Matrix<Type>::operator [](int subscript)` же!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34079/discussion-between-overthesanity-and-vladd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, `#pragma once` и «стражи включения» служат одной цели — поэтому дублировать их не нужно, либо используйте pragma либо стражи(это справедливо для MSVS, да и для других, но, в целом, pragma once не является частью стандарта).

Далее, есть пара «трюков» как можно разделить шаблон на два файла и чтобы это всё ещё и компилировалось. Трюк первый, «обратное включение»: берём наш cpp файл и включаем его в заголовочный:

```
#pragma once
template <typename Type>
class Matrix {
private:
    int rowCount;
    int columnCount;
    int size;
    Matrix *ptr;
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int, int);
    ~Matrix();
    void setMatrix();
    void getMatrix();
    Type* operator [](int);
    Matrix operator+(const Matrix &);
    Matrix operator-(const Matrix &);
    Matrix operator *(const Matrix &);
    Type *minPositive();
};

#include "matrix.cpp"
```

Но это ещё не всё, чтобы это работало, нам нужно `matrix.cpp` исключить из сборки, для этого `правой кнопкой по файлу->свойства->Исключить из сборки`(или как там это будет в русскоязычной студии). «Решение» просто поражает своей «элегантностью», но все довольны: задание преподавателя выполненно, студенты могут спать спокойно.

---

Есть и другое решение, которое уже можно считать подходящим. Т.к. у нас есть класс матрицы, то мы примерно представляем с какими типами мы можем встретиться, поэтому мы явно инстанциируем шаблоны в cpp файле, с типами данных, которые могут использоваться с нашей матрицей. Где нибудь в cpp файле(в начале, или конце) пишем:

```
template Matrix<double>;
template Matrix<int>;
template Matrix<float>;
```

Можно добавить и больше типов, если хочется.

---

Но, разумеется, правильным методом использования шаблонов является написание всего кода шаблона в одном заголовке. 2 метода, описанные мною выше, интересны академически, но представляют мало ценности в реальной жизни.