# Как написать шаблонную функцию, которая в качестве аргументов принимала бы только целые числа, без дробных?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Вопрос в заголовке. Моих знаний не хватает для ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: Использовать концепт [`is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral). Задали бы вопрос подробнее, с примером кода — получили бы и ответ подробнее...

Comment: Что будет делать функция - неважно, здесь главное с какими аргументами она будет работать - только с целыми любого типа на входе.
Если нужно больше конкретики, то функция принимает десятичное целое число любого типа и возвращает число разрядов в аргументе.

Comment: На текущий момент такую задачу можно выполнить, прописав несколько функций (с перезагрузкой) для каждого типа. Но поскольку я новичок в программировании, могу не знать более правильного, оптимального варианта выполнения задачи.

Comment: Для начала напишите просто шаблонную функцию, принимающую в качестве аргументов любые типы, затем добавьте в нее `static_assert`, проверяющий, что типы целые посредством трейта `::std::is_integral`

Comment: Булевой тип тоже будет тру, как на него проверить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вас устроит?

```
template<typename T>
requires (is_integral_v<T> && !is_same_v<bool,T>)
int digits(T d) 
{
    int r = 1;
    while(d /= 10) ++r;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: `<source>:4:30: error: parentheses are required around this expression in a requires clause`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [Договорились](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v6nbEGGsb) :) P.S. Просто я живу с VC++, он понимает и без скобок... :)

Comment: У меня в Эклипсе не компилится. Как только добавляю вызов функции (я назвал её width) в функции main(), так вылезает ошибка:

Building target: siu.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++  -o "siu.exe" ./src/siu.o ./src/siu_main.o   
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: ./src/siu_main.o:siu_main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference to `int siu::width<int>(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:58: siu.exe] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

Comment: А без вызова в main() - компилится.

Comment: Вы что, вынесли шаблонную функцию в отдельный .cpp-файл??!! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/195342  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/12586/195342

Comment: Да, отдельно хедер, отдельно определение, и функция main() в отдельном файле для проверки.

Comment: Всё, заработало, большое спасибо.